# Does damage transferred to a shield guardian count as damage the shield guardian has taken?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage

This is relevant for effects that trigger when damage is taken such as if the shield guardian is wearing another shield guardian's amulet.

> If the guardian is within 60 feet of the amulet's wearer, half of any damage the wearer takes (rounded up) is transferred to the guardian.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing part of this, but I don't understand how there is a question here.  It seems like an obvious "yes" to me, but I don't want to answer incorrectly

Comment: @goodguy5 It says damage is transferred not damage is taken. These types of questions have come.up before regarding resistances etc.

Comment: ah, I see. okay then. Will post an answer.

Comment: Just FYI that “title says it all” is something to avoid. The question body should be used to ask the question and spell out any important details, and the title should just be relied on as a summary for display on various pages and search results. “Title says it all” drives editors up the wall. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sorry. I just couldn't think of a way to rephrase the question. Guess I really don't have to.

Comment: Yeah, on this question it turned out that there's no need to rephrase. (As a helpful guide, I try to imagine people reading the question without ever seeing the title, so that it's complete & clear on its own. I often write titles only after writing the question, too.)

Comment: Does this question answer the same question as "How is damage transferred if one is wearing multiple Shield Guardian amulets?"?

Comment: @goodguy5 I don't think so. That is a separate bottle entirely

Answer (score 5):

## It counts as damage

Damage does not have a precise definition in the rules, but there is no reason to believe that damage transferred from one creature to another is not still just damage. Creature A is taking damage and half of that damage is taken by the Shield Guardian. As a result the Shield Guardian's hitpoints drop. Sound, looks, and smells a lot like damage to me.

There are many effects where damage is taken by multiple creatures from the same effect. This case is no different.

Comment: Do you could chain a bunch of shield guardians together, yes?

Comment: @DavidCoffron There is nothing in how the damage works that would prevent it at least. That sounds like another question to address in full though.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

Damage is Damage is Damage. 5th edition has often explained to go with "common English interpretation" rather than specific wording.

If damage is transferred from one target to another, that damage is "dealt" to the second (or third in the case of your shield guardian chain).

You can look at Cloakers and Rugs of Smothering (they have the "Damage Transfer" special quality) as examples.

> **Damage Transfer**.
>  While attached to a creature, the cloaker takes only half the damage dealt to it (rounded down) and that creature takes the other half.

<sub>P.S. - I wonder who is the "causer" of the secondary damage, though...</sub>

Comment: Regarding the PS about the cause of the secondary damage, I'd argue that the source of any transferred damage (barring specific rules that say otherwise) would be the same as the source of the original damage - even if some other ability/trait causes the damage to be transferred/duplicated to another creature besides the one that was originally targeted.